# Vertical ScrollBar for subnodes only

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a problem where a node in a TreeView has so many subnodes that they can't be displayed all at once on the screen. on the right side i have a scrollbar for the whole treeview. but when i scroll it down, it moves the treeview to the next node - not a subnode. It means that those subnodes outside of visible area can never be displayed. i wonder if it's possible to add one extra scrollbar that would only serve for scrolling subnodes a node. It would appear only if a node has more subnodes than it is possible to display on the screen at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you need to take a look at the [`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From the linked page:

> Content in a ScrollViewer can be scrolled in terms of physical units or logical units. Physical units are device independent pixels. Logical units are used for scrolling items within an ItemsControl. The default behavior of the ScrollViewer is to use physical units to scroll its content. However, in cases where the CanContentScroll is set to true, the content could use logical units to scroll. For example, ListBox, ListView, and other controls that inherit from ItemsControl use logical units to scroll. If CanContentScroll is true, the values of the ExtentHeight, ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and VerticalOffset properties are number of items, instead of physical units.
>
> If you require physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling, wrap the host Panel element in a ScrollViewer and set its CanContentScroll property to false. Physical scrolling is the default scroll behavior for most Panel elements.

So just try adding `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` to the declaration of your `TreeView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that didn't help. It's a quite complex example of a treeview - a lot of styling, triggers. In HierarchicalDataTemplate there is a lot of markup code as well. HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate there is a grid surounded by a Border. and that's wrapped by another Grid on top. I'm saying that because the simplest example of treeview i created actually works as expected - scrollbar scrolls through all elements of the tree. Here there's something blocking this default behaviour.

Comment: @user3046525, you must realise that *you* are the only person who can fix your code in this case, as you're the only one with all of the information/code. I have shown you how to alter the scrolling mode on the `TreeView` and there's nothing more than I can really do. All I can suggest is for you to try to simply your problem by copying parts to a new WPF Application until you either have a small working example that demonstrates your problem (which you could then post here), or you find the problem and can fix it on your own. Good luck.

Comment: that's what i'm doing actually. i merely wanted to thank for the feedback. once i know what was wrong i'll give a proper answer in this thread.

Comment: in the end you're exactly right. CanContentScroll property was the key.